# How to advertise my other iphone apps within ios application?

Tags: ios, iad

I am developing an iPhone application. In this app, I want to advertise my other iPhone apps that are live in the App Store. I want to show the pop up for my other apps randomly and whenever the user clicks on them. Then, we can redirect to download that application from iTunes.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Question is a bit too broad. Please specify what exactly do you find yourself having a hard time dealing with? How to show pop ups? How to design pop ups? How to redirect users to iTunes from your app? Is there a way to directly download other apps from yours? How to randomly show pop ups that you have already created?

Comment: Search google for "implement crosspromotion in ios" or something like that and then ask on SO if you have concrete issues.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for your quick reply,I need to advertise my all other apps which is currently live on app store so for that I want to design pop up having name of particular app and show it in my application and by clicking on it,it should redirect to itunes from my app so user can simply download it from itunes.

Comment: Remind me not to use any of your apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can advertise other apps. One would be to open a modal viewController on every Xth app launch where you randomly show one of the apps. In order to redirect the user to the app, use the following code snippet:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.com/apps/APPNAME"]];
```